# How to reload table data using socket.io

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io, pug

I have an array of data that gets automatically updated every few seconds. That array is used to load a table into an html page using pug. I want to have the table reloaded using sockets.io, without needing a page refresh.

Here is how I load the data into the table, once the page is accessed.

```
tbody#rows
    each row in table
         tr
            td= row[0]
            td= row[1]
            td= row[2]
            td= row[3]
            td= row[4]
```

I'm using sockets.io to send the request to update the page, like this:

```
io.emit('updateTable', main.getTable());
```

Is there any way to render pug code into html outside of a route, because then I can load the html using jquery?

Comment: Managed to do it. I created a new route for 'tableData' which renders the pug file into html using the data, and using JQuery I loaded the html from that route into the table.

Answer (score 1):

You should subscribe on table data and then instead of request page reloading you should request table data:

**Server side:**

```
client.on('requestTableData', () => {
  client.emit('tableData', YOUR_TABLE_DATA);
});
```

**Client side:**

```
server.on('tableData', data => {
  // render table data
});

function requestData() {
  server.emit('requestTableData');
}
```

Comment: I was not sure how I would render the html like that, I can pass the data to the server using the sockets, the problem was displaying it. I managed to do it using new routes instead, to render the pug file into html.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are talking about AJAX or socket, and it should be done at the client/browser side, not on the server.

you can buid a WebSocket connection on your page, and update the table after you get new data.